# Dynamic CSS class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to create a `margin` class in my custom CSS like `margin-left-x` and wish to have the left margin equal to that `x` value. Is this possible? More precisely I wish to do it as below:

```
.margin-left-x{
   margin-left: x%;
}
```

Brute force approach is to create separate CSS classes for each margin value but it becomes tedious and difficult to maintain, like:

```
.margin-left-2{
   margin-left: 2%;
}


.margin-left-5{
   margin-left: 5%;
}


.margin-left-20{
   margin-left: 20%;
}
```

Is there anyway I can make this dynamic with just a single CSS class?

In my HTML, I wish to use it in the `class` attribute directly, like below:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 margin-left-20">
 <p> Hello </p>
</div>
```

Comment: it could possible but you have to generate the definition for all classes using the meta-programming concept. You can look it up otherwise I would say use javascript.

Comment: You could use a SCSS loop to generate the rulesets (although that would cause bloat). A [function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function) would work too.

Comment: As others have indicated, you'd need a bit of pre-processing for this. However, if you are going to write class=margin-left-20 it's not much different from writing style="margin-left:20%" and no need to remember to put all the stuff into the stylesheet. Or set a CSS var.